# Can I use a Mac os x 10.6.6 that came with a newer iMac to install it on another one?

Tags: snow-leopard, imac

I recently purchased a brand new 27" iMac that came with snow leopard as the default os. I was wondering if I could use the back up disc that it came with to install it on my old 21" iMac that is 5 years old. I have seen on various forums that the discs that come with computers are machine specific, and thus the result is a message stating that "Mac OS X Snow Leopard cannot be installed on this computer." But I've heard there are workarounds to this. Does any one know what they are? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the gray installation CD you probably won't be able to do it because they are machine specific, but its worth a try. If you boot from the CD & it is not compatible with the machine it will just tell you to press the power button to turn off your machine. Then just boot normally & eject the CD, no harm done.